# Unable to merge column data in groupBy function in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I tried to merge single column data by using Laravel Eloquent.
Below are the code

```
$verifications = AllVerification::where('user_id', Auth::id())
->where('tag', $tag)
->get()
->groupBy('emp_id')
->values();
```

Output:

```
[[
 {
    "id":1,
    "tag":"EVI89XG",
    "user_id":1,
    "emp_id":2,
    "verification_id":3,
    "created_at":"2020-11-10T07:42:26.000000Z",
    "updated_at":"2020-11-10T07:42:26.000000Z"
 },
 {
    "id":2,
    "tag":"EVI89XG",
    "user_id":1,
    "emp_id":2,
    "verification_id":4,
    "created_at":"2020-11-10T07:42:26.000000Z",
    "updated_at":"2020-11-10T07:42:26.000000Z"
}]
```

Expected Output

```
{
    "tag":"EVI89XG",
    "user_id":1,
    "emp_id":2,
    "verification_id": [{3,4}]
    "created_at":"2020-11-10T07:42:26.000000Z",
    "updated_at":"2020-11-10T07:42:26.000000Z"
}]
```

Please help me to solve this problem.
Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

```
  $expected_output = [];    
  foreach ($verifications as $data) {
        $unique_key = $data['user_id'] . "_" . $data['emp_id'] . "_" . $data['tag'];
        if (array_key_exists($unique_key, $expected_output)) {
            $expected_output[$unique_key]['verification_id'][] = $data['verification_id'];
        } else {
            $expected_output[$unique_key] = $data;
            $expected_output[$unique_key]['verification_id'] = [$data['verification_id']];
        }
    }

    print_r(array_values($expected_output));
```